# when I push code to salesforce error happen

Tags: profile, admin

> force-app\main\default\profiles\Admin.profile-meta.xml  
> You may not modify the permission Access Tracer for External Data Sources while editing a Standard Profile

it is ok to push code to salesforce when use old scratch org. when I create new scratch org then above error appear. I do not change any thing.

Comment: What editions are the scratch orgs? Are their definition files identical? Was one of them created prior to the release of Winter '20?

Comment: @DavidReed I m facing the same issue `You may not modify the permission Access Tracer for External Data Sources while editing a Standard Profile` can you please help me

Comment: @Hunt I was asking the original poster to clarify their question. Tagging me doesn't help anything here. If you have a more detailed account of how to replicate this issue, open your own post so the community can assist.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Unfortunately Salesforce ScratchOrg have some weird limitations, that are applicable to Sandboxes and Production org. Which does not make any sense for the ScratchOrg. As many people would like to have a Profile in source control. But due to this limitations, profile must be tweaked to remove some parts not deployable to the ScratchOrg.

Long story short. From you Admin profile xml remove these lines:

```
<userPermissions>
    <enabled>true</enabled>
    <name>TraceXdsQueries</name>
</userPermissions>
```

Then try to push it again

Comment: You have definitely saved my weekend nights of sleep!

Comment: Worked for me too!!